# Combobox selection show System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have simple combo box templates as shown below:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalForegroundBrush" Color="Black" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#4c4c4c" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" >               
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource NormalForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton ClickMode="Press" x:Name="ToggleButton" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Focusable="False" Grid.Column="2" />
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="3,3,23,3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                    <TextBox Margin="3,3,23,3" Visibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Background="Transparent"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{x:Null}" IsReadOnly="False" Focusable="True" xml:space="preserve" />
                        <Popup Placement="Bottom" x:Name="Popup" Focusable="False" AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" PopupAnimation="Fade">
                            <Grid MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Border BorderBrush="#FF646464" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
                                        <ItemsPresenter KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                           </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                     </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                        
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ContentSite" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>                     
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>       
</Style>
```

And WPF Window as shown below:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Name="combo1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"></ComboBox>

</Grid>
```

C# code is:

```
  private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable("table1");
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));           
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));

        table.Rows.Add(25, "David");
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Sam");
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Christoff");
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Janet");
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Melanie");

        combo1.DataContext = table;
        combo1.DisplayMemberPath = "Patient";
        combo1.SelectedValuePath = "Dosage";
    }
```

When I set property as IsEditable=True, combobox works fine but when that property is False, its shows selected item as System.Data.DataRowView. Is there any problem in style?

Comment: try to shorten the code, u putted here so that it is easy to read. Dont just write the entire code

Comment: Hi as you have an collection of System.Data.DataRowView binded to ComboBox , hence the selected item will be of type ' System.Data.DataRowView '

Comment: I know there is some problem in style and I am not good in it. So I have put all styles used by this combobox. Actual code without style is already short. But I am sorry if you have problem reading it.

Comment: @ethicallogics: But If I remove combobox style then this code works fine. So I think there is problem with style.

Comment: What is the exact problem ? what do you expect in SelectedItem property of the comboBox? and i dont think binding do have any concern with the style.

Comment: why you posting that much of code try to reduce with simple and where you cause the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was problem with style as I said, I missed to add ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" in ContentPresenter. This was resolved when I added it.